# if function statement for each document in a firestore collection node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to create an if statement for the 'one' and 'two' functions, however when i am creating it i can't seem to make the statement run for each document. So i took it out and ran them buy them selves and they both work fine right now, but not sure how to wrap it in a condition for it to loop through each document in a collection .

any tips or pointers will be massively appreciated

thanks

```
const {
    initializeApp,
    applicationDefault,
    cert,
} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {
    getFirestore,
    Timestamp,
    FieldValue,
} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const firebaseConfig = {
    xxxx,
};

const serviceAccount = require("xxxxxx.json");

initializeApp({
    credential: cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = getFirestore();

async function one() {
    const foodRef = db.collection("xxxxx");

    const snapshot = await foodRef.where("item", "==", 2).get();

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
    }

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());

        const res = doc.ref.set(
            {
                fatIntake: "50",
            },
            { merge: true }
        );
    });
}

async function two() {
    const foodRef = db.collection("xxxxxx");

    const snapshot = await foodRef.where("item", "==", 1).get();

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
    }

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());

        const res = doc.ref.set(
            {
                fatIntake: "10",
            },
            { merge: true }
        );
    });
}

one();
two();
```

Comment: is this supposed to be java or javascript?

Comment: javascript, my bad i changed the tag

Comment: What `if` statement in the code you shared isn't working? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have wrong if condition

In function `one` you put the following if statement

```
const snapshot = await foodRef.where("item", "==", 2).get();
```

You put `item == 2` instead of `item == 1`. No mistake in the condition but the logic I suppose. Atleast what I think is the mistake. And the same problem is with function `two`

Also, confirm the field name `item`. This should exactly match the name in firestore, and it shouldn't be inside any other sub map.

If that is not the case and not what you asked then please elaborate more and precisely what your problem is.

The syntax and call to the if statement is correct. Actualy it is a `query` not an if statement. so, your `query` is syntatically correct.